# Error: Effect dispatched an invalid action: undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am trying to write an effect for my action. It has 2 service methods: `getData()` and `checkToken()` inside.

It will throw an error:

> "ERROR Error: Effect "IndexEffects.loginStatusValidate$" dispatched an invalid action: undefined"

What should I do ?

```
 @Effect()
  loginStatusValidate$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(IndexActionTypes.LoginStatusValidate),
    switchMap(() =>
      this.authService.getData().pipe(
        map(oldToken => {
          if (oldToken) {
            console.log("oldToken exsits");
            this.authService.checkToken().subscribe((newToken) => {
              console.log(newToken);
              // Throw error if I try to dispatch action here
              return new LoginStatusValidateSuccess(newToken);
            });
             // It's fine if I just dispatch action here
             //return new LoginStatusValidateSuccess('');

          } else {
            return new LoginStatusValidateError();
          }
        })
      )
    )
  );
```

```
 getData() {
    return of(localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN'));
  }
```

```
 checkToken(){
      // access api refresh token 
      return of("newToken");

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `this.authService.checkToken().subscribe((newToken) => {`, by doing this you're not returning something, you're returning `undefined`.

You're subscribe, instead you must return a stream of actions, like you do with `this.authService.getData().pipe`.

Comment: Thank you, but I did do this at first time, still throw same error. So I change to subscribe, nothing change.

Comment: make sure you're returning an Action